# Trying to acces MySql database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new at ASP.NET MVC and I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application with my own MySQL database. I've customized the code to connect to the database and i think everything has to work fine. When i use my own testdata in DeelnemerRepository (UserRepository in english) I don't have any problems but when i try to access the database it throws an ArgumentException. The exception also gives me the following message:

> Unable-to-find-the-requested-Net-Framework-Data-Provider-It-may-not-be-installed

The invoked method in the DeelnemerRepository:

```
public IQueryable<Deelnemer> FindAll()
{
    return deelnemers.OrderBy(d => d.Emailadres);
}
```

With NuGet i added MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entities and MySql.Web

The Connection strings in the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjectDynamische-20130415102959;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjectDynamische-20130415102959.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="kindermishandeling_dbContext" connectionString="server=localhost;Port=3307;User Id=root;password=1234;database=kindermishandeling_db;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I also found out there could be a problem in this method in this class but I'm not sure:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't expect a solution for the problem but i just would like to know where i have to look, I think ASP.NET MVC is really complicated...

Comment: Which version of the MySql data assemblies do you have installed? I don't think all versions support entity framework

Comment: MySql.Data 6.6.5, MySql.Data.Entities 6.5.4.0, MySql.Web 6.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by myself. Anyway thanks everyone who tried to help me.
I had to add this code to my web.config file:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```